Theme of VS Code doesn't change
The color of search, options, and information areas turned into light blue in my VS Code.
(https://i.sstatic.net/Xt0Yxycg.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/8tsCsqTK.png)
I tried deleting the file settings.json, changing the valors of the settings file, reinstalling the program, deleting my theme extensions and didn't work.

Just a guess, but might be workspace settings, which are stored in the project / repository: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings. They also override the user settings.
